# Joining two tables and retrieving records from new table in Mysql

Tags: mysql

I have two tables student(crn,age,name) and account(crn,account_id,fee). I want to get account_id of students whose age is less than 20. How can i do that in MySQL?

Comment: select a.account_id 
from students s 
join account a on s.crn = a.crn 
where age < 20;

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT account_id, name, age 
FROM student s inner join account a on s.crn = a.crn
where age < 20
```